# Traversing a directory tree in C++

Tags: c++

This is been a curiosity of mine for a while: how do you traverse a directory tree without using boost or any third-party library? Just plain ol' C++ (examples in 98, 99, 01, 0x and 1x specs are okay.)? It was done back in the day before boost existed so there's got to be a way to do it.

Comment: You know, boost *is* C++, it's not magic.  If you can't use boost, you can still *look* at boost and see how it does what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the adoption of the C++17 standard there exists a `<filesystem>` header included in the language that does exactly this. See your compiler's documentation to determine if it's supported.

Answer (score 6):

Please take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirent.h

The reference also has a link to dirent.h implementation for Windows or you can use cygwin

If you want to just do it for Windows you can build upon this example

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: `"Microsoft Visual C++ does not include dirent.h"` Sadly, this is the compiler I'm using. :(

Answer (score 4):

There are no standard filesystem functions, so you won't get any answers that use "plain C++".  For POSIX systems, [opendir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir) is used.  For Windows, [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418.aspx).  I'm not sure about other OSes.

There's a reason people recommend Boost Filesystem—it's portable and takes care of all these details for you.